# How to check which range a float variable is within, from database values

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have the following sql table "tax_info" with three columns:

[image]

I have a variable called "Salary" which is a floating point. How can I check which tax bracket Salary lies within? Please note there could be as many tax brackets as necessary, but currently there are only 3. So far I've started off with the following, but unsure how to query.

```
  PreparedStatement ps4 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT FromSalary, ToSalary  FROM payroll_system.tax_info");
               ResultSet rt = ps4.executeQuery();
```

Comment: `where $someval between fromsalary and tosalary`

Comment: How would that $someval look given my Salary variable?

Comment: Use http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp to select TaxBracket where salary >= FromSalary and salary <= ToSalary.

Comment: Note that the values in the table leave uncovered ranges, For example wheat is the tax bracket of salary = 6000.5 ?

Comment: @c0der hmm...How can I account for the uncovered ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java naming convention is for variables to start with lowercase letter, so you variable should be named `salary`, not `Salary`.

Float values only have about 7 digits of precision ([6 to 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)), so it is a very bad datatype to use for salary. Since your tax brackets are defined as 0-6000, 6001-20000, ..., a salary of 6000.42 will fall between brackets. This means that your salary value is likely an integer value, so you should use `int`, not `float` to store the value.

When using JDBC, you must remember to close the statements and result sets, otherwise you have a resource leak. Best way to do this is using try-with-resources.

Here is code to find the tax bracket for a given `salary` value.

```
// input: con, salary
int taxBracket = 0, fromSalary = 0, toSalary = 0;
String sql = "SELECT TaxBracket, FromSalary, ToSalary" +
              " FROM payroll_system.tax_info" +
             " WHERE ? BETWEEN FromSalary AND ToSalary";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, salary);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            taxBracket = rs.getInt("TaxBracket");
            fromSalary = rs.getInt("FromSalary");
            toSalary   = rs.getInt("ToSalary");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To allow the last tax bracket to be open-ended, change the `ToSalary` value to null.

```
TaxBracket FromSalary ToSalary
========== ========== ========
1          0          6000
2          6001       20000
3          20001      NULL
```

You would then modify the code as follows:

```
String sql = "SELECT TaxBracket, FromSalary, ToSalary" +
              " FROM payroll_system.tax_info" +
             " WHERE FromSalary <= ?" +
               " AND (ToSalary >= ? OR ToSalary IS NULL)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, salary);
    stmt.setInt(2, salary);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            taxBracket = rs.getInt("TaxBracket");
            fromSalary = rs.getInt("FromSalary");
            toSalary   = rs.getInt("ToSalary");
            if (rs.wasNull())
                toSalary = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `getInt()` returns `0` when value is null, which is why we have to check for null.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm by the way, if you look at my table, what should I do if I want to make tax bracket 3 from 20001 but no ToSalary for that? As any salary greater than 80000 in this case would not return a bracket

Answer (score 1):

You can use between like that:

```
SELECT TaxBracket
FROM payroll_system.tax_info
WHERE $value between FromSalary and ToSalary
```

Just set the $value variable for the salary you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the tax bracket so no point in returning the salaries only.

```
String p =  "SELECT TaxBracket, FromSalary,ToSalary" 
           +"FROM payroll_system.tax_info"
           +"WHERE FromSalary <= ?"
           +  "AND ToSalary >= ?";
PreparedStatement ps4 = con.prepareStatement(p);
ps4.setFloat(1,Salary);
ps4.setFloat(2,Salary);
ResultSet rt = ps4.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, this is irrelevant to the code and I'm not sure you know the answer to this, but should payroll admins be allowed to change these tax thresholds if the government makes changes? Or should it be managed by someone else?

Comment: @javaprogrammer that really sounds like an internal company policy question so I can't know the answer to it.